# What are environment properties for Payara InitialContext from free standing Java Client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I've abandoned GlassFish 4-point-anything in favor of Payara41. Amazingly GF has unresolved JDBC and JMS Resources configuration bugs. See: 
[Glassfish Admin Console throws java.lang.IllegalStateException when creating JDBC Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048435/glassfish-admin-console-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-creating-jdb)

Payara perfectly fixed the JMS configuration issues.  So all I need are the environment properties my standalone Java Client needs to get an InitialContext(env) to lookup() those Resources.

Note:  InitalContext() doesn't work in a standalone.  Only in an EJB Container that can look up the {Payara Home}/glassfish/lib/jndi-properties file.  That file has one property so that's what I have in my code below:

Key:     "java.naming.factory.initial"

Value:  "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory"

That set off a series of NoClassDerfinitionFound Exceptions that led me to add these jars with these classes to my client's buildpath, and to /glassfish/lib/. They are in the order I encountered them.

"glassfish-naming.jar"   w/ "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory"

"internal-api-3.1.2.jar" w/ "org.glassfish.internal.api.Globals"

" hk2-api-2.1.46.jar "    w/ "org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator"

"appserv-rt.jar" from glassfish/lib added to client build path

But now my code throws a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for Globals.getDefaultHabitat().  Please note, below the Exception doesn't get caught in my catch block.  (And I don't see it in Payara's service.log either.)

I know my client finds Globals.class, because adding it caused the NoClassDefinitionFound for ServiceLocator.  Are there two "Globals.class" out there ... one w/ and one w/o that method.  Or is the "Lorg" in console output really different from "org", i.e. is there a "Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator"?

I'm stuck.  And this seems such a bread and butter kind of need -- environment properties a standalone Java client needs to get Payara's InitialContext -- it would be nice to be able to add it here for everyone to use (in addition to the jars I've already located.)  I'd love to see Payara soar, because I love its Admin Console compared to JBoss and MayFly's XML orientation.  Any suggestions?  I'm stumped.Code and console output follows:

Code

```
package org.america3.testclasses;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.america3.toolkit.U;

public class Test2 implements MessageListener {

  static final Properties JNDI_PROPERTIES = new Properties() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    {/*This property key:vlaue pair is specified in Payara41/glassfish/lib/jndi-properties*/
     /*The class it calls for is in Payara41/glassfish/lib/glassfish-naming.jar*/
     this.put ("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");}
  };

  //constructor
  public Test2 () {
    String iAmM = U.getIAmMShort(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
    System.out.println(iAmM + "beg");
    try {
      Context jndiContext = (Context) new InitialContext(JNDI_PROPERTIES);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("    " + iAmM + "InitialContext failed to instantiate");
      System.out.println("    " + iAmM + "Exception     : " + e.getClass().getName());
      System.out.println("    " + iAmM + "e.getMessage(): " + e.getMessage());
      System.out.println("    " + iAmM + "e.getMessage(): " + e.getCause());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(iAmM + "end");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test2 messageCenter = new Test2 ();
  }

  public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
}
```

Console

```
Test2.<init> ()                    beg
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.internal.api.Globals.getDefaultHabitat()Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory.<init>(SerialInitContextFactory.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.america3.testclasses.Test2.<init>(Test2.java:24)
    at org.america3.testclasses.Test2.main(Test2.java:36)
```

PS: Could someone with enough points add a "Paraya" tag below.  I mean with Glassfish's console throwing exceptions when used to configure any JNDI or JMS Resource I think many people will switch.

Answer (score 1):

JAR internal-api-3.1.2.jar is for Glassfish v3, and its Globals class has a method getDefaultHabitat() that returns Habitat:

```
public static Habitat getDefaultHabitat() {
    return defaultHabitat;
}
```

However, Glassfish v4 has changed method signatures, and you have to use new Glassfish v4 internal API whose Globals class has appropriate method getDefaultHabitat() that returns ServiceLocator:

```
public static ServiceLocator getDefaultHabitat() {
    return defaultHabitat;
}
```

In other words, replace internal-api-3.1.2.jar with internal-api-4.1.jar which can be found on Maven Central [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/main/common/internal-api/4.1/internal-api-4.1.jar)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm almost there (I hope).  Your solution cleared up the the MethodNotFound Exception.  Now I get NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/module/ModulesRegistry.  I'll try to hunt down that class and try to be sure I have the one for 4. This  has been killing me so I'm running behind and slow.  Mañana.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! You can find your missing class in hk2-core JAR. Take care that it should be on the same version as hk2 API (2.1.46), here is the link: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/hk2/core/2.1.46/core-2.1.46.jar

Answer (score 0):

You should add `${PAYARA-HOME}/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar` to your classpath as this references all the other required jars in it's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Please note, it uses relative path references so you really need to install Payara on the client machine.