# IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() when creating oracle connection pool in glassfish

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to make an oracle connection pool in my glassfish server. I had a glassfish instalation that was defaultly bundeled with netbeans. After I removed netbeans I donwloaded and now have a separate glassfish folder. On the glassfish from netbeans I had no problem making a connection pool, but when I try to do it on the stand-alone version(the one I downloaded) I get the error :

[image]

From the `server.log`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:777)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:851)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:504)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:642)
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:202)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:127)
at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Is the problem coming from the glassfish bundeled with netbeans that I removed. And how can I fix this ?

Comment: if you are using glassfish 4 - this is known glassfish issue (bug), they haven't resolve this yet (I had same week ago: 25-Oct-2015) and we've already had the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048435/glassfish-admin-console-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-creating-jdb

Comment: Hmm kind of strange, why it had no problems on netbeans. I mean the the version is the same, so there should be a problem there as well.

Comment: And they have this as an issue since february, seriously ?

Comment: different versions? one more question - do you use windows or unix? bcz I didn't have the problem on windows7 but got it on Ubuntu

Comment: yeap... since feb, and we have time to found work around

Comment: @are I'm using windows 8.1, and had no problem on the netbeans bundeled one.

Comment: net beans uses GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1, you downloaded 4.1.1. you can download 4.1 from glassfish portal and use it until they release stable version of 4.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I faced the same problem on windows, and it resolved be delete my glassfishe from Prgramfile folder and download new version from http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/4.0/promoted/glassfish-4.0-b87.zip 
and extract it where you want but not in programfile beacuse it need admin roll
and then creat new server.