# Cannot create a JDBC Resource or Connection Pool

Tags: jdbc, nullpointerexception, glassfish, admin, connection-pooling

I have recently installed GlassFish v4.1.1 on my computer (Windows 8.1).

When I execute my GlassFish Server and enter in the administration webpage(http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf from the NetBeans project), I obtain:

[image: Admin webpage]

When, when I press the button "Create New JDBC Resource" or "Create new JDBC Connection Pool" the following error appears:

[image: error]

I really do not understand what is going on. Could you help me please ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's just a bug in the GF admin tool. Upgrade GF. If it still reoccurs, report it to GF guys. GF 4.0 is pretty ancient though. Just try the most recent version, perhaps in flavor of its community successor [Payara](http://www.payara.fish).

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. I downloaded and installed GlassFish v4.1.1.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048435/glassfish-admin-console-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-creating-jdb You might want to consider switching to Payara, it is a fork of Glassfish and does fix errors.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you so much for your answer. Finally, I have decided to take Papaya and it works very well.

Comment: When looking for a solution to the same problem using GlassFish v4.1.1 on Windows 10. I saw this question and I'm comming back to share my solution. it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue and I found a solution: instead of creating the connection pool using my IDE (Netbeans), I used the command line:

My DB username is `root` with `an empty password` and I'm working on my `localhost`.
My table is named `tmpDb` and the pool `myPool3`.

Here is the used command

```
$> cd "c:\Program Files\glassfish4\bin"
$> asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --restype  javax.sql.DataSource --datasourceclassname org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource --validationmethod table --validationtable DUAL --property User=root:Password="":ServerName=localhost:tmpDb --ping true myPool3
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works ! Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate :)